# OpenGL: Sending RGBA color struct into glColor*() as one parameter?

Tags: c++, opengl

Is there some way to send a struct like:

```
struct COLOR {
    float r, g, b, a;
};
```

directly into glColor*() function as one parameter? Would make the code nicer.

I could make own function and send separetely each R,G,B,A values onto glColor4f() but that wouldnt be that nice. So im looking a way to send it the most optimal way as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
COLOR color;
glColor4fv((GLfloat*) &color);
```

Update:
I wouldn't recommend creating an inline function, however, you could use GLfloat in your struct to get the expression clearer. Use &color.r to avoid a compiler warning.

```
struct COLOR {
  GLfloat r,g,b,a;
};
COLOR color;
glColor4fv(&color.r);
```

Comment: hmm, is it possible to make it any cleaner from that?

Comment: @Newbie: You can just do `glColor4fv(&color.r)`, assuming `GLfloat` is just `float`.

Comment: should i make `inline void glColor(const COLOR &color){ return glColor4fv((GLfloat*)&color); }` ? would clean up the code, but im not so sure about using gl function looking function names... also does it make it faster if i use `&color.r` rather than `(GLfloat*)&color` ? if i make my struct use GLfloat instead could i just use `&color` ?

Comment: Well, because immediate mode is really slow for anything serious. Vertex arrays via interleaved vertex buffers is the way to go. If you'll run into performance problems, it won't be because if the non-inlined functions (which is a compiler hint, by the way). For cleaniness you can use class that has operator const GLFloat* or just a union.

Answer (score 3):

The most optimal way of sending vertex data is Vertex Arrays, it will also make your code look nicer, you should take a look.

Comment: i dont always want to create vertex arrays for little things since the optimizing would be useless

Answer (score 1):

to make the code of calling glColor4fv simpler,  
 
i prefer writing a small class to encapsulate the color values and   
 
use operator overloading to to convert to float * automatically.  
 
Ex:

```
class MyClr
{
public:
MyClr(float r, float g, float b, float a)
{
    m_dat[0] = r;
    m_dat[1] = g;
    m_dat[2] = b;
    m_dat[3] = a;
}
// if needed, we can 
// overload constructors to take other types of input like 0-255 RGBA vals
// and convert to 0.0f to 1.0f values

// wherever a float* is needed for color, this will kick-in
operator const float* ()const { return (float*)m_dat;} 

private:
float m_dat[4];
};

// usage
MyClr clrYellow (1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

// to send to OpenGL
glColor4fv(clrYellow);
```